# Count character is consecutively repeated the most times in the given string

Tags: ruby, string

Anybody know, how to count the character is consecutively repeated the most times in the given string. I need very shortest answer.

For ex: "xxyyydduuummm" will return 'y, u, m'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"xxyyydduuummm".scan(/((.)\2*)/).group_by{|s, c| s.length}.sort_by(&:first).last.last.map(&:last) (Ruby 1.9)
"xxyyydduuummm".scan(/((.)\2*)/).group_by{|s, c| s.length}.sort_by{|k, v| k}.last.last.map{|s, c| c} (Ruby 1.8.7)
# => ["y", "u", "m"]
```

**Improvement** Suggested by  Mladen Jablanović.

```
"xxyyydduuummm".scan(/((.)\2*)/).group_by{|s, c| s.length}.max.last.map(&:last) (Ruby 1.9)
"xxyyydduuummm".scan(/((.)\2*)/).group_by{|s, c| s.length}.max.last.map{|s, c| c} (Ruby 1.8.7)
# => ["y", "u", "m"]
```

Comment: thanks sawa. But, it's not working for me. I have using rails 1.2.1 version with ruby 1.8.6

Comment: A slight variation: `"xxyyydduuummm".scan(/((.)\2*)/).group_by{|r,c| r.length}.max.last.map(&:last)`

Comment: Sorry!. It's also not working.. "xxyyydduuummm".scan(/((.)\2*)/).group_by{|r,c| r.length}.max.last.map(&:last)
TypeError: wrong argument type Symbol (expected Proc)
THIS IS MY ERROR.. undefined method 'group_by'. My ruby version is 1.8.6

Comment: hi sawa, it shows the following error..  undefined method `group_by' for #<Array:0xb7f24254>

Comment: @Mr. Black. `group_by` is defined on Ruby 1.8.7+. Ruby 1.8.6 was released more than four years ago. I suggest you upgrade to at least Ruby 1.8.7. Some people do not upgrade to the current 1.9.2 for compatibility reasons, but 1.8.7 is fully compatible with 1.8.6. There is no reason to stay on that.

Comment: @ Mladen Jablanović Thanks for the improvement. I added it to my answer.